# efficient looping procedure to find the longest common substring java

Tags: java, algorithm, twitter, jersey, substring

I retrieved 200 tweets using `jersey` API. I want to find two tweets which have the `longest common substring`. This is what I have got. `tweetList` is an `ArrayList` of `Tweet` Objects. `comapreTweets` method compares tweet objects for longest substring.

```
Tweet t1=new Tweet();Tweet t2=new Tweet();
    int longestString=0;

    for(int i=0;i<tweetList.size();i++)
    {int store=0;Tweet comparer=null;
        for(int j=i+1;j<tweetList.size();j++)
        {
            if(j!=i){
            int result=tweetList.get(i).compareTweets(tweetList.get(j));
            if(result>store){
                store=result;
                comparer=tweetList.get(j);
            }}
        }
        if(longestString<store)
        {
            longestString=store;
            t1=tweetList.get(i); t2=comparer;
        }
}
```

If I retrieve 200 tweets then this will loop approx. 40000 times. I require a more efficient way.

**EDIT**
This loop also compares same tweets in inverted order
Suppose my `tweetList` contains `{a,b,c,d}` ; when `i=1` and `j=3` the comparison is between `b & d`; when `i=3` and `j=1` the comparison is `d & b`. How to avoid this.

**SOLUTION** instead of `j=0` it should be `j=i+1`. It loops for `19701` times.

Comment: You might consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com for optimization of working code.

Comment: You may also consider reading about this problem on Wikipedia. I'm not quite sure if you're talking about the [Longest common substring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) or [Longest common subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) problem. I'm guessing you want the subsequence one, but these should provide a good introduction. Note especially the section on "Complexity" - not all problems in computer science have known, more efficient solutions. You may have run into one of them.

Comment: What would the matching substring be, for your requirements, in this example? `"abcdefghijklm nopqrs tuvwxyz"` and `"hello worldefghijklm nopqrs tuvwat"`

Comment: @durron597 The output is "defghijklm nopqrs tuvw"

Comment: @JamesMontagne - this is an algo question more than a code review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
199 + 198 + ... + 1 = 19900
```

I believe `19900 times` is a sensible answer. Nearly half of the comparisons in your loops are  redundant. You just need to compare the first one to the remaining 199 tweets, the second one to the remaining 198 tweets, and so on. Further optimizaiton better than 19900 times could be possible but I can't think of one off the top of my head.

Comment: This is still `O(n^2)`. Which is not to say it's not better, it is.